# What does mean weaker and stronger terms in logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to understand what does mean the terms *stronger* and *weaker* which I'm reading in *Programming: The Derivation of Algorithms*:

*When $[P\Rightarrow Q]$ holds then $P$ is called **stronger** than $Q$ and $Q$ is called **weaker** than $P$. For example, $x\geqslant 2$ is stronger than $x\geqslant 1$ and $x^{2}\geqslant 0$ is weaker than $x\geqslant 0$. The weakest predicate is predicate true, since $[P\Rightarrow true]$ for all $P$, and the strongest predicate is predicate false, since $[false \Rightarrow P]$ for all $P$.*

I would like to hear examples from daily common language which apply these two terms.

Comment: This is a technical meaning: you can’t expect everyday usage to shed much light on it. An assertion $P$ is stronger than an assertion $Q$ if $P$ implies $Q$; strength here is measured by how much you can infer from the truth of the statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, "stronger" means "tells you more" or "has more implications." If $P\implies Q$ holds, then everything $Q$ tells you, $P$ also tells you.

For instance, "It will rain tomorrow" is a much stronger statement than "It will rain sometime in the future."

Examples of this being used in natural language might be a bit hard to come by. One "near miss" is the phrase "more specific than": saying "it will rain tomorrow" is more specific than saying "it will rain sometime in the future," and frequently "more specific than" is interchangeable with "stronger than."

---

In general, though, I wouldn't look too much to natural language for explanation of formal concepts. Here's an example of where the phrase "stronger than" can be used in natural language in a very misleading (for this context) way: I've heard people describe "Candidate A will win in a landslide" as a *stronger* prediction than "Candidate A will narrowly win," despite the fact that formally of course the two statements are contradictory. Why is "stronger" an appropriate term to use in this context, from a natural language perspective? Well, it could be because the former statement is in some sense more "extreme" than the latter; or it could be that each statement can naturally be thought of as a comment on the *strength* of Candidate A, and the former asserts more strength. It could even be connected to the assumed state of mind of the speaker: the former statement suggests that the speaker has high (=strong) confidence in Candidate A's chances of winning, while the latter suggests less. Regardless, this usage does *not* line up with the formal one, but is in fact something I've heard used in real life.

Tl;dr - natural language is weird. Don't rely on it too much for intuition.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Respect to the examples given in the book, what do they say you?: $x\geqslant 2$ is stronger than $x \geqslant 1$ and $x^{2}\geqslant 0$ is weaker than $x\geqslant 0$.

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez ["$x\ge 2$" is stronger than "$x\ge 1$"] means exactly what it says - the statement "$x\ge 2$" implies the statement "$x\ge 1$." Similarly (but reversed, since it's about "weaker than") with the other example. I'm not sure what you mean by "what they say to" me.